# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException al seleccionar valor de input

Tags: java

En mi programa, cuando uno ingresa al menú de consultas se le pide al usuario una serie de datos. Al llegar a la sección donde ingresa el mes de su nacimiento este menú no aparece, se cierra el programa y aparece la siguiente excepción:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
    at CapturasDatos.main(CapturasDatos.java:63)
```

La sección del código que produce el error es la siguiente:

```
String[] Mes = {"Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"};
mes_opcion = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Selecciona","MES DE NACIMIENTO",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,Mes,Mes[11]);
```

¿A qué se debe el error?

Comment: El error se debe a la falta del mayo. Mataste un més entero. Java nunca perdona algo así. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Donde defines

```
String[] Mes = {"Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"};
```

Tienes todos los meses, menos "Mayo". Eso hace que dicho arreglo tenga solo 11 elementos (numerados del 0 al 10, esto es, desde `Mes[0]` hasta `Mes[10]`).

Al intentar llamar a `Mes[11]`, se lanza la excepción dado que no existe dicha posición en el arreglo.